# Anonymous surveys

Tags: civipetiton, civisurvey

I get that 'normally' you'd want to verify survey respondents by email, but there are instances where that's not possible / desirable. Is it possible to set up an anonymous survey on CiviCRM that would function?

I have a situation where I'd like to survey children's thoughts on some services we're offering. They are all under 13yrs.

They're all using laptops in a coding club (provided by us), so an online survey seems obvious. I could use GoogleDocs or Typeforms, but I'm using CiviCRM so wondered about using the built in survey / petition functions.

I could set up a dummy 'Anon' account and use that to collect the data, but would that then work from an analysis perspective? I'd have hundreds of responses (as activities), but against a single individual.

Or should I stick to Typeforms & dump the csv into excel?

Using WP 4.9.5 / Civi 4.7.31

Comment: What is wrong with having all the Activities against the one contact? It doesn't sound like it makes the analysis any harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could certainly use CiviCRM in the method you're describing, I'm not sure it's a great fit.  CRMs are inherently about tracking constituent info; this data must be separate from your constituents.  And while CiviCRM's webforms are adequate, it's certainly not such a great feature that I'd try to work against the software.

I think a third-party tool, or something like Caldera Forms for WordPress is a better option.